# CakePHP save not working when load model dynamically based on switch case

Tags: php, cakephp

This is my sample code:

```
switch($topic_type) {
    case 1: //post
        $model = 'Userposts';
        $field_name = 'user_post_id';
        $select_name = 'post_title';
        break;
}
$model = ClassRegistry::init($model);
$model->alias = 'TP';
$model->id = $topic_id;
$result = $model->find('first',
            array(
                'conditions'=>array($field_name=>$topic_id),
                'fields'=>array($select_name.' as topic',$field_name.' as id'),
                ));
 if(!empty($result)){
    $this->updata[$model_name][$select_name] = $modified_topic;
    $this->updata[$model_name][$field_name] = $topic_id;
        if($model->save($this->updata)){
            $respArr['token'] = $token; 
            $respArr['status'] = 1; 
            $respArr['msg'] = 'Success'; 
            echo json_encode(array('token' => $token, 'status' => 1, 'msg' => 'Success'));exit;
        }
 }
```

The $model->find is working and fetching result where as $model->save after find is not working.

field_name is the primary key and select_name is the save that i want to update after modifying title.

Comment: Use variable `$model` instead of `$model_name` to update data

Comment: @Sadikhasan i used that initially but ti throw error as $model is model object and not string model_name is string which contains same string as 'Userposts'

Comment: Your  model  should be `$model = 'Userpost'` insteead of `$model = 'Userposts';`. Correct your model name.